# pick the smallest value associated with a parameter

Tags: excel, vba

Suppose I have an Excel file arranged this way

```
A -- B -- C
1    5    2
2    5    1
3    2    0
4    2    10
5    4    12
     1    14
     1    3
     4    7
     3    9
```

I need to look for the smallest value in C associated to the value in B that matches the value in A.

To make it clear, if I pick 1 in A, I'd like to obtain 3 from column C (1 in B is associated with 14 and 3).
I should do it looping over all the parameters in A.

Thanks to anyone willing to help me.

Answer (score 2):

No *VBA* is needed.  In **D1** enter the Array Formula:

```
=MIN(IF($B$1:$B$9=A1,$C$1:$C$9))
```

Copy **D1** down through **D5**:

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Comment: Yours is less typing.

Answer (score 2):

A formula approach:

```
=MIN(IF($B$1:$B$9=A1,$C$1:$C$9,""))
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then copy down.

[image]

Comment: Fantastic approach! *vbg*

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2010 or later you can use the following non CSE standard formula:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,$C$1:$C$9/($B$1:$B$9=A1),1)
```

It operates the same as the MIN(IF()), but without the need of hitting Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

So you would again put it in an empty column and drag down.

[image]